# rocksdb pinned immutable memtables memory unlimited growth

Tags: linux, memory, memory-leaks, rocksdb

i do not set any config about db memory control(default memtable size is 64M, and max memtable number is 2), but db's used memory unlimited growth.
then i debug some param:

befor call flush:

```
rocksdb.cur-size-all-mem-tables：72027512（72M）
rocksdb.size-all-mem-tables：4766069920（4.7G）
```

after call flush

```
rocksdb.cur-size-all-mem-tables：728
rocksdb.size-all-mem-tables：4694043136（4.7G）
```

and according to the RocksDB annotation：

```
//  "rocksdb.cur-size-all-mem-tables" - returns approximate size of active
//      and unflushed immutable memtables (bytes).
static const std::string kCurSizeAllMemTables;

//  "rocksdb.size-all-mem-tables" - returns approximate size of active,
//      unflushed immutable, and pinned immutable memtables (bytes).
static const std::string kSizeAllMemTables;
```

that mean pinned immutable memtables occupied so much memory, and unlimited growth.

so i want to know how to avoid pinned immutable memtables memory unlimited growth

Answer (score 0):

Most likely, those memtables are held by iterators not destroyed. Check whether you leak any iterators. If there are iterators intentionally kept to reuse, consider to call Refresh() periodically on all of them to release memtables and files pinned by it.

It is also possible that they are held by other operations, e.g. compactions, but given this huge gap, it is unlikely to be the case.